# Can't Count - Number of Comparison Operations

Tags: c

So I have this segment of code that was given to me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) 
   {
     if (arr[j] < arr[i]) 
     {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
     }
   }
}
```

I am trying to calculate the number of **comparison operations** that would occur if the code were to run.

There's the initial comparison all the way up to i=100. so there's 101 comparisons for the outer loop. The inner loop also has 101 loops, but that comparison within will only happen 100 times due to the j=100 will not have that comparison occurring.

I've made a tries but none of been the right answer so far.

I've had 101 x (101+100) = 20301 which is not the right answer.

I've searched for this on google and came up with a question identical to this but was answering how many assignment operations that occur which I was able to answer on my own. Which btw is 25201.

Comment: Outer loop will run 100 times - 0=>99.   Same with inner loop.  100x100 = 10000 total

Comment: @tkausl it runs 100 times but there are 101 comparisons (the 101st comparison fails, ending the loop)

Comment: The condition is checked every loop.  Since you have 100 outer loops and 100 inner loops for each outer loop you have 10,000 total checks.

Comment: Both the inner and the outer loop are identical. Both the outer loop, and each iteration of the inner loop, make 101 comparisons. 100 comparisons for values 0 through 99, and the 101st comparison that fails, ending the loop. So, the number of comparisons in both loops is 101 + 100*101=10201. The comparison inside the inner loop should execute 100 * 100=10000 times. The total number of comparison I count is 10201+10000, or 20201, and not 25201. I have no idea how you get 25201.

Comment: _"25201 assignments"_ Where did you get that number from? `i` is initialized to 0, 1 assignment. it is then incremented (`i++` == `i = i + 1` 100 times), that's 101 assignments. For 100 of those 101 assignents, `j` undergoes the same treatment: 100*101 assignments. `i` and `j` together make up for 10201 assignments already. That's a given. Any other assignment depends on the values in the array, but there's a theoretical maximum of 14850 inner assignemnts (counting 3 assigments). So there's a total number of 25051 possible assignments AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 comparisons on the outer loop drive 101 + 100 comparisons on the inner loop. There is one more comparison on the outer loop to detect loop termination, so:

```
100 * (101 + 100) + 101 = 20201.
```

Instrumenting the program:

```
outer_cmps=0;
total_inner_cmps=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   ++outer_cmps;
   inner_cmps=0;
   for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) 
   {
     ++inner_cmps;
     if (arr[j] < arr[i]) 
     {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
     }
     ++inner_cmps;
   }
   ++inner_cmps;
   tota_inner_cmps += inner_cmps;
}
++outer_cmps;
total_cmps = outer_cmps + total_inner_cmps;
```

Comment: Oh I see my mistake now. Thank you for clarifying it.

Answer (score 2):

I got 20201.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    unsigned long count;

    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; ++count, i < 100; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; ++count, j < 100; ++j) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    (void) printf("%lu\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You see, Virginia, there are uses for the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

So that would be 100*200+100+1=20101

(100 times i, which runs the j loop 100 times, which performs 1 comparisson `if (arr[j] < arr[i])` per loop, and one `i` loop that fails when `i==100`and 100 times `j` loop that fail when `j==100`)